# Удаление названия скрипта из url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть скрипт, который принимает на вход два `get` параметра:

```
mysite.com/do.php?from=file&act=replace
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы к этому скрипту можно было обращаться по адресу

```
mysite.com/file/replace
```

?

Comment: возможно. `mod_rewrite`, `RewriteRule` ваши ключевые слова для поиска и решения этой задачи, в случае если речь идет про сервер apache

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен в том, что вам нужно именно то, что вы хотите, но именно в этом случае для Apache будет следущий конфиг в файле `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ do.php?from=$1&act=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Но это не есть правильное решение, однако работать будет, по аналогии можно написать правило для Nginx:

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /do.php?from=$1&act=$2 break;
  }
}
```

Однако повторюсь что надо еще 10 раз подумать прежде чем применить данное правило.